# Counting number of rows with a group by clause

Tags: database, postgresql

I've got some answers to a questionaire stored in a table, and I want to count how many unique `responses` to a certain `campaign` are made. Preferably within one (sub)query

These are the relevant tables

**cr_campaign**

```
id, name, ..... meta ....
```

**cr_answers**

```
id, campaign_id, response_id, question_id, answer, ts
```

Where the response_id is a unique identifier per response, with multiple tupples in the `cr_answers` table.

eg:

```
56 | 1 | 'efghays' | 34 | 'Answer' | 2014-04-01 13:59:08
57 | 1 | 'efghays' | 35 | 'Answer to other question' | 2014-04-01 13:59:08
58 | 1 | 'zlxkjgh' | 34 | 'Answer by other person' | 2014-03-30 15:45:35
```

I tried this query, but the subquery returns more then one row, because it `counts` the tuples within the group by instead of the total of rows returned.

```
SELECT *, ( SELECT count(*) 
            FROM cr_answers 
            WHERE campaign_id = cr_campaign.id 
            GROUP BY response_id
          ) as responses
FROM cr_campaign
ORDER BY actief
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a certain campaign with id `_id`

```
select count(distinct response_id) as responses
from
    cr_answers a
    inner join
    cr_campain c on a.campaign_id = c.id
where c.id = _id
```

For all campaigns

```
select c.id, count(distinct response_id) as responses
from
    cr_answers a
    inner join
    cr_campain c on a.campaign_id = c.id
group by c.id
order by c.id
```

Comment: group by is also ordering - no need for the order by

Comment: @blue Although it is likely that an ordered set will be returned, specially for small ones, there is no guarantee.

Comment: Thank you for the response! But it does not take in account the response_id. It returns 3 responses, but it should be two: as there are two persons who answered the campaign. (distinction by the `response_id` column.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto - in fact it is guaranteed! Read the manual ;)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto - [By default, MySQL sorts all GROUP BY col1, col2, ... queries as if you specified ORDER BY col1, col2, ... in the query as well.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html) Anyway, you've got my up vote, cheers :)

Comment: @blue This question is tagged Postgresql not MySQL

Comment: @blue: This question is for PostgreSQL, and there's nothing in the PostgreSQL docs saying that GROUP BY implies ORDER BY...  So unless it's part of some SQL standard, I don't think your claim generally applies.

Comment: ouch - my fault. 10x!